# printing a string backward

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a piece of code that reverses strings around. So far it works but there are spaces between every character in the string and it says none before and after the printed result. What could I do to fix this?

```
def reverse(text):
    length = len(text)
    while length > 0:
        print text[length - 1],
        length -= 1
```

Comment: I don't see "none" anywhere. It just prints the string backwards (albeit with a space after every character, because of Python 2's `print` behavior).

Comment: you can show some example for what you are expecting and what getting.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is doing `print reverse(sometext)` which would account for a `None`

Comment: @PM2Ring, I think you are right. But OP says *it says none before and after the printed result*. What about the first None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the `None` issue. And the space you are getting between characters isn't an issue, rather print in python2 works like that.  However you can ignore the spaces with a simple change in your code. Like this:

```
def reverse(text):
    length = len(text)
    result=''
    while length > 0:
        result += text[length - 1]
        length -= 1
    print result

reverse("I love python!")
```

Output:

```
!nohtyp evol I
```

Comment: If you can't reproduce the issue, and therefore are not including a fix for it, how does this answer the question?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I answered it because the answer partially and mostly solves the problem OP states. The other problem OP faced can be due to improper calling of the function as PM2Ring said before. I have seen a bunch of answers with lot of upvotes in SO which partially solves a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the "none" problem, just the spaces between the characters.  For the "none" problem, make sure you're passing the function a string and not something like a list.  If you're passing it a string, then the nones are coming from someplace else.  And as PM 2Ring suggested, make sure you aren't attempting to print the result of the function call, since the function as written doesn't return anything.

The spaces are due to the way print works, and the fact that you're printing the result one character at a time.  A better way would be to reverse the string, then print the result in a single print.  This can be done very simply as follows:

```
rev = text[::-1]
```

Comment: If you can't reproduce the issue, and therefore are not including a fix for it, how does this answer the question?